# Mac => Samsung HDMI - No Sound

Tags: audio, hdmi

I have connected an HDMI cable between my Samsung Smart TV and MacBook Pro running Sierra.

The option for output displays lists my TV but it says “display port” where I believe it should say HDMIi. I tried a lot of the methods I found online with no success.

Comment: We stream from a Retina MacBook via HDMI (plugged into the MB's MiniDisplayport) to a TV. Picture works fine, but to get audio from the TV, we use a separate audio cable from the MP to the TV. Clumsy, but it works.

Comment: So you plug a male hdmi cable in the side of the Mac directly and the other end male hdmi cable in the TV? And you are playing non HDCP video that you perhaps have in Photos taking a movie recording yourself?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I guess it is due to the adapter. I worked around it by adding an extra cable from mini jack to stereo cinch just for outputting the audio. The mini jack audio output is located on the other end of you MacBook.